# How to read a path and get a value

Tags: unix

I have a file with a particular path. I need to read it and get a value. It has values in first line only, the rest of the file is blank like this:

```
P0002282004                 P
```

I want the value "p" in a variable. I am using SunOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
variable=`cat /path_to_file/file.txt | awk '{print $1}'`
```

This will read first column of the file you have and store it as variable (obviously this file must only contain that value).

Otherwise you can adjust with head -1 if you only want the first value as a variable.